# Qt - No matching function for call to ‘QVariant::QVariant(MyClass&)’

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm having trouble creating a `QVariant` with a custom type. Here is a small example that shows what I want to achieve:

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

int main() {
  MyClass some_object;
  QVariant variant(some_object);
  return 0;
}
```

include/MyClass.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <QtCore>

class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() : _my_member(0.0) {}

  MyClass(const MyClass &other) { _my_member = other._my_member; }

  ~MyClass() {}

  MyClass& operator=(MyClass& other)
  {
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
  }

  MyClass(MyClass&& other) : MyClass()
  {
    swap(*this, other);
  }

  friend void swap(MyClass& first, MyClass& second)
  {
    using std::swap;
    swap(first._my_member, second._my_member);
  }

private:
  float _my_member;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass);
```

The build fails with the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘QVariant::QVariant(MyClass&)’
  QVariant variant(some_object);
                              ^
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: have you read this? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/custom-types.html it seems more a problem that your type is not really registered as one of qt's meta types

Comment: Unrelated to CMake. Please edit the tag out.

Comment: @Hayt Yes, I have read this site and followed its instructions.

Comment: @usr1234567 Sorry, I fail to see how this is not related to CMake. Edit: You are right. It was indeed not related to CMake.

Comment: @user2925177 this is a compilation problem. This is more a Qt usage problem and not cmake. In the example linked in the article the Variant value is set with `QVariant stored;  stored.setValue(message);` Have you tried this?

Comment: The assignment operator should take const MyClass& other as argument. please correct this error as a first step because this is a fundamental error.

Comment: @user2672165 Personally I think you are right, but I was following the copy-and-swap idiom as explained in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). Note that the use of the `swap` function within the assignment operator invalidates the const correctness, so it is impossible to use `const` there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling `QVariant`'s constructor with an instance of `MyClass`: there is no such constructor in [`QVariant`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html). What you're looking for is [`QVariant::fromValue`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#fromValue):

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main() {
  MyClass some_object;
  QVariant variant = QVariant::fromValue(some_object);
  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`QVariant::setValue`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#setValue):

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main() {
  MyClass some_object;
  QVariant variant;
  variant.setValue(some_object);
  return 0;
}
```

**Note:**

To retrieve the value from QVariant, you will have to use the template method [`QVariant::value`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value), optionally with [`QVariant::canConvert`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#canConvert):

```
if (variant.canConvert<MyClass>())
    MyClass retrieve_object = variant.value<MyClass>();
```

**Note2:**

Looks like you tried to implement [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom/3279550#3279550). Your `operator=` should be:

```
MyClass& operator=(MyClass other)
{
  swap(*this, other);
  return *this;
}
```

Instead of:

```
MyClass& operator=(MyClass& other)
{
  swap(*this, other);
  return *this;
}
```

If you perform a swap with a reference, `other` will be modified, and I doubt you want it.

Answer (score 6):

To make `QVariant` object from your class use [fromValue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#fromValue) method of `QVariant`:

```
QVariant variant = QVariant::fromValue(some_object);
```

You have error, because there is no such constructor in `QVariant` with parameter of type `MyClass&`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I feel stupid for not having tried this out.

Comment: It is fundamentally wrong trying to use QVariant::QVariant(MyClass&). Should to begin with try to use QVariant::QVariant(const MyClass&).